# How to set C# SerialPort object using NLUA?

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

I'm initializing Lua in my app next way:

```
lua = new Lua();
lua.LoadCLRPackage();
lua["SerialPort"] = new SerialPort();
lua.DoFile("script.lua");
```

And add to project System.IO.Port to create SerialPort objects. So,my sctript containing next:

```
import ('Mynamespace')
import ('System.IO.Ports')
local myport=SerialPort("COM7",9600)
```

after exec I have an exception:attempt to call global 'SerialPort' (a userdata value)

What should I change to use next construction: SerialPort(String,Int 32)
and get access to fields "BaudRate","PortName" SerialPort objects in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add "local myport={}" before "myport=SerialPort" and its allowed me to set fields baud rate and port name.

```
import ('ManipulatorGUI')
local myport={}
myport=SerialPort
myport.BaudRate=9600
myport.PortName="COM6"
myport:Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code worked for me:

```
Ports = CLRPackage("System.IO.Ports", "System.IO.Ports")

port = Ports.SerialPort("COM5", 9600)


port.Open(port)

print(port.ReadTimeout)

port.WriteLine(port,"Hello");

port.Dispose(port)
```